# Line contains invalid enclosed character data or delimiter at position

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was trying to load the data from the csv file into the Oracle sql developer, when inserting the data I encountered the error which says:

Line contains invalid enclosed character data or delimiter at position

I am not sure how to tackle this problem!

For Example:

```
    INSERT INTO PROJECT_LIST (Project_Number, Name, Manager, Projects_M,
Project_Type, In_progress, at_deck, Start_Date, release_date, For_work, nbr, 
List, Expenses) VALUES ('5770','"Program Cardinal 
(Agile)','','','','','',to_date('', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'','','','','');
```

The Error shown were:

> --Insert failed for row  4
>
> --Line contains invalid enclosed character data or delimiter at position 79.
>
> --Row 4

Comment: Is `to_date('', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` - empty string date- accepted in oracle SQL?

Comment: @TSion.D.P - that expression is valid in Oracle, it evaluates to NULL (in DATE data type).

Comment: Does the input data use the double quote `"` to enclose values? If so, the double quote before the word Program may cause the error. It should be escaped somehow; as it is, it may be interpreted as the end of the column value, so the parser expects a delimiter right after it, and instead it gets the letter P. The double quote in the column value seems wrong anyway - where it the matching closing double quote?

Comment: Well, you have the exact position of the problem, line 4 position 79, can you please share it **exactly** with us ?

Answer (score 3):

I've had success when I've converted the csv file to excel by "save as", then changing the format to .xlsx. I then load in SQL developer the .xlsx version. I think the conversion forces some of the bad formatting out. It worked at least on my last 2 files.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using the concatenate function in my CSV file first and then uploaded it on sql, which worked.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it doesn't like `to_date('', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`. It's missing a date to format. Is that an actual input of your data?

But it could also possibly be the double quote in `"Program Cardinal (Agile)`. Though I don't see why that would get picked up as an invalid character.

Comment: I didnt add the to_date part under the start date it just as the format as YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: This guess would be incorrect. Oracle is perfectly happy with that call, and it returns NULL (of DATE data type).

Comment: @mathguy Cool deal. Thanks. I didn't realize to_date() would return a NULL for a blank date. Though I've likely hit that issue in my past Oracle work. :-S

Comment: @Shawn - I don't work in IT, so I am sure I never hit that before; and I didn't know. I just tested it - it took ten seconds.